# Unknown error after importing an Eclipse project to Android studio

Tags: java, eclipse, android-studio

After I imported an old project in Android studio and build it, it throw bunch of errors. And I can't find a solution. I think there is something wrong with resource files, but I don't know how to fix them.

These are the first errors:

```
Error:(1) Attribute "actionOverflowButtonStyle" has already been defined
Error:(1) Attribute "actionBarStyle" has already been defined
Error:(1) Attribute "actionBarSplitStyle" has already been defined
Error:(1) Attribute "actionBarWidgetTheme" has already been defined
Error:(1) Attribute "actionBarSize" has already been defined
Error:(1) Attribute "actionBarDivider" has already been defined
Error:(1) Attribute "actionBarItemBackground" has already been defined
Error:(1) Attribute "actionMenuTextAppearance" has already been defined
Error:(1) Attribute "actionMenuTextColor" has already been defined
Error:(1) Attribute "actionModeStyle" has already been defined
Error:(1) Attribute "actionModeCloseButtonStyle" has already been defined
Error:(1) Attribute "actionModeBackground" has already been defined
Error:(1) Attribute "actionModeSplitBackground" has already been defined
Error:(1) Attribute "actionModeCloseDrawable" has already been defined
Error:(1) Attribute "actionModeShareDrawable" has already been defined
Error:(1) Attribute "actionModePopupWindowStyle" has already been defined
Error:(1) Attribute "textAppearanceLargePopupMenu" has already been defined
Error:(1) Attribute "textAppearanceSmallPopupMenu" has already been defined
Error:(1) Attribute "actionDropDownStyle" has already been defined
Error:(1) Attribute "dropdownListPreferredItemHeight" has already been defined
Error:(1) Attribute "spinnerDropDownItemStyle" has already been defined
Error:(1) Attribute "homeAsUpIndicator" has already been defined
Error:(1) Attribute "actionButtonStyle" has already been defined
Error:(1) Attribute "selectableItemBackground" has already been defined
Error:(1) Attribute "dividerVertical" has already been defined
Error:(1) Attribute "activityChooserViewStyle" has already been defined
Error:(1) Attribute "popupMenuStyle" has already been defined
Error:(1) Attribute "textAppearanceSearchResultTitle" has already been defined
Error:(1) Attribute "textAppearanceSearchResultSubtitle" has already been defined
Error:(1) Attribute "textColorSearchUrl" has already been defined
Error:(1) Attribute "listPreferredItemHeightSmall" has already been defined
Error:(1) Attribute "listPreferredItemPaddingLeft" has already been defined
Error:(1) Attribute "listPreferredItemPaddingRight" has already been defined
Error:(1) Attribute "dropDownListViewStyle" has already been defined
Error:(1) Attribute "listPopupWindowStyle" has already been defined
Error:(1) Attribute "textAppearanceListItemSmall" has already been defined

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
```

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\22.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

So that we are clear, the project worked fine in Eclipse, but after importing it to the Android studio, this happenned.

Comment: Did you export build.gradle from eclipse first?

Comment: No. Did I have to? That project was sent to me zipped, so I just unzipped it, and imported.

Comment: Open in eclipse then follow this the exporting from eclipse section, then import the build.gradle in AS http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/migrating-from-eclipse-projects

Comment: Ok, but I don't have Eclipse installed on this PC. So, should I install and do like told in the link? Or, is there another way?

Comment: Personally i would recommend doing that yes, atleast everything will be correctly done.